# Consolidating several folders into one folder

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I was working on Excel for a couple of days and I tended to save my work in more than one place.

I am trying now to consolidate these folders and files under the `C:` drive and using one folder with several sub folders.

I am unable to rename these folders and transfer them to the new folder that I created: the error message being that the files are open in another application.

This clearly is not the case.

How do I copy these files and rearrange them in a new folder?

Comment: For take this the wrong way, but you say “this clearly is not the case.” So why is it so clear to you? Because I can tell you beyond a shadow of a doubt the files/folders are open somewhere and that is why Windows is saying that. By open, it could simply mean you are viewing the folder in windows explorer.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of this but I was unable to find any open files even after rebooting.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Process Explorer:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

[image]

And search for your file:
[image]

In such a way you may be able to find which program is blocking your file from being closed.

Then once you have found the problem you should be able to copy your files as normal.

> Source:
>
> https://www.javelin-tech.com/blog/2012/02/file-is-open-in-another-program/